# How to get value especific from ModelForm field in django framework?

Tags: django, field, modelform

I am creating one web system and need to get one value especific from ModelForm for store in another system, in addition to storing in django. Example:  get field "nome" from Model Form for to store in LDAP server

model.py

```
class Orientado(models.Model):
   nome = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
   telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
class OrientadoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Orientado
        fields = ['nome', 'telefone','email']
```

views.py

```
def person_new(request):
form = OrientadoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
autor = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('person_list')
return render(request, 'person_form.html',{'form': form, 'autor': autor})
```

html

```
{% block main %}

<h3>Novo Orientado</h3>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {{ form.source.errors }}
    {{ form.source }}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't know why you would do `User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`. You *already have* the user: it is `request.user`. There is no need to query it again.

Comment: But I don't understand your question at all. What problem are you having with this code?